# End of subsheet without corresponding start Blueprism

Tags: blueprism

I encountered an error trying to step or run any process involving my custom excel VBO.

After stepping the End stage it gives me this error "End of subsheet without corresponding start"

Even if the process it's in another page and using 2 stages (start linked to end)

I think the problem is in the excel VBO I modified, but inside this, there are no errors detected by Blueprism

Regards!

Comment: Why can't you use standard MS EXCEL VBO? What do you need?

Comment: There are some actions not included, like searching an item. So I created some pages to add funcionalities and all they currently work fine, but then, that error appeared. I'll try to isolate the issue to find out the stage with issue.

Comment: Can't you just record macro(this item searching) in excel and then run it from BP?

Comment: The standard MS Excle VBO is so small! We here have already have around 209 actions in our object compared to 69 in standard one.

Comment: Check if ALL pages have start linked to end, especially Initialize and Clean up - I deleted start-end connection in clean up, when I was learning BP and was pulling my hair for a while until I figured it out.

Comment: Please check here for answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49107089/8923830

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Internal : End of subsheet without corresponding start' in blue prism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49097207/internal-end-of-subsheet-without-corresponding-start-in-blue-prism)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure why nobody has pointed this out yet but the error you are describing has nothing to do with the underlying app description.

The error you are getting happens due to page hierarchy and Blue Prism not knowing where you want it to go. For example if you have 3 pages

Main page
Page 1
Page 2

If you start on main page and flow (step or play) into page 1, when you get to end of page 1 it will go back to the main page (where the page reference was  called from). If you go main page into page 1 into page 2, at end of page 2 it will go to page 1 because that's the page that called it and likewise at end of page 1 it will go to main page. Blue prism will always try and go to the main page and stage as that's the default end point. The same is true for flow inside actions of objects. When you flow down it needs to know where to flow back to. Likely what you have done is started your flow on a sub page or action page and when you get to the end stage blue prism has no idea where to go back to. You're not on the main page and stage so blue prism throws a flow error saying now corresponding start stage I.e. I've come to an end stage but I have no idea where you want me to go next. So make sure your flow is continuous throughout the hierarchy and that should remove this error.

Answer (score 1):

To avoid this error, start your process run from the main page. 
This occurs when you run a process from other pages on your studio other than the first page (main page.)
However your process still stays as successful but you would get that error message you pointed out.