# 'Internal : End of subsheet without corresponding start' in blue prism

Tags: blueprism

I encountered an error 'Internal : End of subsheet without corresponding start' in blue prism after stepping the end stage in process studio,can anyone knows what the error means and when it comes?

Answer (score 4):

This happens when BP "gets lost" after the end of a page because it was not directed to the page using a Page Reference stage to begin with.It can happen if for example you are using Set Next Stage a bit too freely jumping between pages instead of following a more linear approach to debug your process. I would suggest to reset and try a more linear approach.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in above answer,  blue prism gets lost in the page flow. To fix this you can try using step out when you reach the end of the sub page.

Answer (score 0):

You can get this error in Process Studio, if you have started the Execution of the sub-page using "Set Next Stage" option by right-clicking on Start Stage or any of the stages of the sub-page.
Once this reaches the End Stage on the sub-page, it will throw this error message as the Main Page did not make a call to the sub-page.

So you should always first add page reference on Main Page and then run the sub page from Main Page to avoid this error.

I am not sure but there can be other reasons also for this error.